# c++ efficient large file parser

Tags: c++, parsing, logging

### Question

I'm looking for a more efficient way to create a smaller subsection of a log file containing 50,000-400,000+ lines where each line contains ~50 values. Simple example:

```
   log file                                subsection log file
x   y   z   a   b   c                      a   b   c
1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 ...                4.0 5.0 6.0 ...
1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 ...    -->         4.1 5.1 6.1 ...
...                                        ...
```

### Current Implementation

My current implementation takes ~3 minutes which seems quite slow.

```
int main() {
  string input_file_name = "<path/filename>";

  motion path;
  string line;

  ifstream input_file(input_file_name);
  ofstream output_file(input_file_name + "_parsed");

  vector<string> line_split_values;
  for (line; getline(input_file, line); entry_num++) {
    boost::algorithm::split(line_split_values, line, is_any_of("\t "), boost::token_compress_on);

    // extract data points
    vector<string> line(7);
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      line[i] = line_split_values[3 + i];
    }
    output_file << boost::algorithm::join(line, ",") << endl;
  }
  input_file.close();
  output_file.close();
}
```

Comment: apparently you want to retain the part after the first N characters of each line. i would could that up that way.

Comment: I'm getting the selected elements from the line correctly. More so looking for suggestions to decrease the write time.

Comment: Is "subsection log file" your desired output format?

Comment: Compare your execution time to e.g. the time needed by [wc(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/wc.1.html) and run the program several times (if on Linux, the kernel is buffering file data: see http://linuxatemyram.com/ ...); how did you compile your program? BTW, you could simply use [cut(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html)

Comment: @MattStokes: i dunno what could be more clear in what i wrote. anyway, think about the cost of moving a pointer a fixed distance versus splitting and re-combining a string, typically involving a few dynamic allocations. do you think there could be *any* difference in performance. yes most like the performance is i/o bound. but dynamic allocations are still slow.

Comment: Are the log data fields of varying lengths? Does your PC use writeback caching on the disks? else I would think that even 400K lines * 50 values * 10 char per value = 200 MB should give around 40 MB result write on even a 10MB/s disk should impossible give more than 24 sec, unless its impossibly fragmented.

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably try to avoid using `std::vector` and try something more like this:

```
std::ofstream output_file(input_file_name + "_parsed");

std::string line;
while(std::getline(input_file >> line >> line >> line >> std::ws, line))
{
    output_file << line << '\n'; // '\n' should be faster than std::endl
}
```

Assuming your "subsection log file" is your desired output format.

Comment: As a point of reference, this method parses and outputs a 200MB sample data file (50 cols, 400k rows) in around 3 seconds. You can get a faster performance with a C solution (half the speed) but it is much uglier and more fragile than this.